# Auth0 does not persist login on page refresh for email/password

Tags: javascript, reactjs, auth0, auth0-lock

I am using Auth0 as my authentication provider for a SPA using React. I have followed the [Auth0 react tutorial](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/01-login) and [this more detailed tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/complete-guide-to-react-user-authentication/) from their blog.

I am currently just using just email/password authentication. And the authentication works as expected for login/logout, retrieving user info etc.

However, when I refresh the page, the `isAuthenticated` value from the `useAuth0` always returns false. Even after `isLoading` resolves to true, hence I have to log in again.

This behaviour strangely does not occur on Chrome or Firefox. It fails on Brave and Safari.

I noticed in a forum post on Auth0 (another person with a similar problem) that the `Auth0Provider` should be doing a `authorize` call using `prompte=none`, and it is. It also returns a successful `202` shortly after the page loads (but doesn't change `isAuthenticated` to `true`). This call also sets a cookie `auth0.is.authenticated=true`.

```
authorize?client_id=VALUE&redirect_uri=VALUE&scope=openid%20profile%20email&response_type=code&response_mode=web_message&state=VALUE&nonce=VALUE&code_challenge=VALUE&code_challenge_method=S256&prompt=none&auth0Client=VALUE
```

Here is my route that checks the auth state. This component is wrapped in the `Auth0ProviderWithHistory` code as suggested in the Auth0 tutorials.

```
export default function Routes() {
  const { isLoading, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0()

  const getDashboard = () => {
    //determine which dashboard to return
  }

  if (isLoading) return <p>Loading...</p>

  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return (
      <Suspense fallback={<p>loading...</p>}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            {getDashboard()}
          </Route>
          <Route path="/customer/:customerId">
            <Customer />
          </Route>
          <Route>
            <NotFound />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Suspense>
    )
  }

  return <SignInAndRegister />
}
```

I have noticed when I reload the page, and call the `loginWithRedirect` function I am not redirected to the Universal Login page, instead there are two token calls (POST and OPTIONS). The POST call response has the following details, should I somehow capture this and saving them to reuse them to login?

```
access_token: "VALUE"
expires_in: 86400
id_token: "VALUE"
scope: "openid profile email"
token_type: "Bearer"
```

As an experiment, I downloaded the react sample on the "Quick Start" section of an application in the Auth0 dashboard to see if the behaviour was replicated there. And it was.

I had the impression that the `Auth0Provider` should be handling the silent authentication automagically, is this not the case?

There are not many options to use with `auth0-react` npm package, so I am not sure what to try next. The only available functions are:

```
getAccessTokenSilently: ƒ (opts)
getAccessTokenWithPopup: ƒ (opts)
getIdTokenClaims: ƒ (opts)
isAuthenticated: false
isLoading: true
loginWithPopup: ƒ (opts)
loginWithRedirect: ƒ (opts)
```

If this isn't possible, it looks like I might have to migrate to the `@auth0/auth0-spa-js` SDK.

Comment: Well, you will have to verify on every reload if the user is authenticated already and then let the user go to that same route otherwise sign him out.  I hope you are saving some auth related info in cookies or local storage.

Comment: Have you checked your auth0 configuration? it seems your configuration is not right.

Comment: Is there a specific configuration to check? The app works to login etc so I know the `domain`, `clientId`, Callback URL, Logout URL and Web Origins are correct as the login/logout normal flows break if they are wrong.

Comment: hi @Charlewis I guess this is an open issue. ref: https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-react-samples/issues/192

Comment: @Sheelpriy this issue is unrelated to my problem. I have added more info to the question.

Comment: Could you see if one of these is related to your issue? https://github.com/auth0/auth0-react/issues/100 OR https://github.com/auth0/auth0-react/issues/82 OR https://github.com/auth0/auth0-react/issues/93. I am having a similar issue with auth0, is it related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63465924/samesite-cookie-error-on-localhost-with-auth0

Comment: Those issues are slightly different from what I am experiencing, I have created an issue on the repo - https://github.com/auth0/auth0-react/issues/101

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The issue was that Brave and Safari both use Intelligent Tracking Prevention (ITP), which was preventing the silent authentication from working.

The solution that worked for me was to enable rotating refresh tokens (via the Auth0 dashboard) and providing additional props to the Auth0 provider.

The two new props to add are: `useRefreshTokens={true}` and `cacheLocation="localstorage"`.

```js
<Auth0Provider
  domain={process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN}
  clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID}
  redirectUri={window.location.origin}
  onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
  useRefreshTokens={true}
  cacheLocation="localstorage"
>
  {children}
</Auth0Provider>
```

Here are the official docs to learn more about rotating refresh tokens: https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/refresh-tokens

Comment: Yep, this fixed my issue too. For anyone else stumbling upon this, here is the github issue for this https://github.com/auth0/auth0-react/issues/101

Comment: With the growth of anti-tracking features by browsers, you'll find that legitimate uses (such as the cookies created by Auth0) are stripped because they could appear to be tracking cookies. Rotating refresh tokens circumvent this issue by storing the refresh token within local storage, or in memory which is not subject to the controls implemented by ITP.

Comment: worth noting this also solves the similar issue in Nextjs's static site generation where auth state does not persist after page change.

Comment: Thanks this was driving me insane for some time until I found this.

Comment: For me, simply adding the `cacheLocation: 'localstorage'` (to JS, in my case) param fixed it - no further steps.