# MERN app session cookie working on firefox but not on chrome and other browsers

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, heroku

So I made a MERN app and everything worked fine locally, so I decided to deploy it using heroku. I created to apps, one for client and one for server and I created my db in mongoDb Atlas and then connected it to my server.
The problem is that when I try using the app on Chrome I can create a user en login but nothing after that. I don't see any cookie appearing and if I log what happens in Heroku I see that my isAuthenticated() function doesn't work (cannot read id of undefined). Then I tried on firefox and everything is working perfectly on this browser. Also it doesn't work on any other browser that I tried, like opera won't even let me register or login a user. I think it has something to do with the session and cookies but I don't see what and I've been scratching my head for days now...
Here is my code in Express for the user Session and Mongo connection :

```
 app.use(
  cors({
    origin: process.env.FRONTEND_URL,
    credentials: true,
  })
)

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.use(
  session({
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {secure: true, maxAge: 10000},
  })
);

// for connecting mongodb Atlas
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});
client.connect(err => {
  const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
  // perform actions on the collection object
  client.close();
});
```

And in the client for my axios requests :

```
const service = axios.create({
baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL,
withCredentials: true, // Cookie is sent to client when using this service. (used for session)
});
```

Comment: Is it something to do with SameSite cookie issue? Could you check the issues tab on Chrome, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63465924/samesite-cookie-error-on-localhost-with-auth0

Comment: Actually I thought it was this at first because I had the sameSite issue but I tried Samesite="none" with secure "true" without any result. The Secure:"true" on itself made the chrome issue disappear from the console